# Chaining ternary operator in PHP

Tags: php, formatting, refactoring

I've got a lot of legacy code like this:

```
return isset($a) ? $a : isset($b) ? $b : isset($c) ? $c : isset($d) ? $d : isset($e) ? $e : '';
```

So it's just chained ternary operator.
It works, but most of the variable names are not $a, but $veryLongAndDescriptiveCorporateVariableNames and it's just unreadable for me.

Is there a better way to refactor this? I tried something like this but I don't know if it's the best and most readable way:

```
    $ar = array(
        $a,
        $b,
        $c,
        $d,
        $e
    );

    foreach ($ar as $k => $v)
        if (isset($v)) 
            return $v;
    return '';
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to check for X variables and then use the first existing one. Seems like a bad coded script to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's Working fine:-

```
$ar = array(
        $a,
        $b,
        $c,
        $d,
        $e
    );

    foreach ($ar as $k => $v)
    {
        echo (isset($v)) ? $v : '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is your friend...

```
return isset($a)
  ? $a
  : isset($b)
    ? $b
    : isset($c)
      ? $c
      : isset($d)
        ? $d
        : isset($e)
          ? $e
          : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

M.Fowler would recommend to replace nested conditional with guard clauses:

```
if (isset($a) {
    return $a;
}   
if (isset($b) {
    return $b;
}
if (isset($c) {
    return $c;
} 
if (isset($d) {
    return $d;
} 
if (isset($e) {
    return $e;
}  
return '';
```

https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses